How can I select multi folders in fileImporter in iOS SwiftUI?
This codes below in macOS SwiftUI allows me to select and import multi folders, but I cannot do the same in iOS SwiftUI, there is no issue or error, after running codes I have no possibility to select multi folders.
 struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowing: Bool = false
    var body: some View {

        Button("Open") {
            isShowing.toggle()
        }
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $isShowing, allowedContentTypes: [.folder], allowsMultipleSelection: true, onCompletion: { results in
            
            switch results {
            case .success(let items):
                
                for item in items {
                    print(item.lastPathComponent)
                }
  
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
            
        })
        
    }
}


As of iOS 18, this is still a bug in SwiftUI. Consider filing a FB to Apple to raise their awareness

If you want to select multiple items from a folder, using allowedContentTypes: [.Item] will enable you to do so.
